# ¿Como visualizar un archivo PDF en el navegador?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

Tengo un proyecto en ASP.NET Web API el cual es consumida por una aplicación web en html, tengo un formulario en el cual envió información  y un archivo PDF, esto lo realice con `formdata`, el archivo PDF se guarda en una carpeta en el servidor con la extensión original y un nombre que le asigno, los demás datos los guardo en la base de datos, así como el nombre que le asigne al archivo.

Todo esto funciona correctamente.
Mi pregunta es cómo puedo visualizar ese archivo que subí al servidor (estoy trabajando de forma local) a través de la aplicación web, y que se muestre en el navegador. He investigado bastante pero aún no he encontrado la solución al problema.

A través del botón identifico el ID del registro en la base de datos, para posteriormente recuperar el nombre del archivo en la base de datos  y poder identificar la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo. Esta es la función que ejecuta el botón:

VerDocumento:

```
         function (param) {
            var IdDoc = param;
            var IdPerAlumno = $('#IdPerAlumno').val();

            if (IdDoc) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: URLExpediente,
                    data: { IdRegDocumento: IdDoc, IdPerAlumno: IdPerAlumno },
                    contentType: 'application/pdf',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (resultado) {
                        var blob = new Blob([resultado]);
                        var link = document.createElement('blob');
                        link.setAttribute('data', blob);
                        link.setAttribute('type', 'application/pdf');

                        window.open(document.body.appendChild(link), "_blank");

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("No se ha subido un archivo para este documento registrado");
                    }
                });

            } else {
                alert("Por favor seleccione un Aspirante");
            }
        }
```

La URL del Ajax es el controlador de la Web API que tiene el método para buscar el archivo que está en el servidor.
Este es el Controlador llamado Expediente y el método que realiza la busque del archivo PDF.

Buscar documento PDF:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage MostrarPDF(int IdRegDocumento, int IdPerAlumno)
    {
        EXPEDIENTEALUMNO documentoExp = LGExpediente.GetExpediente().Find(x => x.IdReg == IdRegDocumento);

        var NombreArchivo = documentoExp.NombreArchivo;

        if (NombreArchivo == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, NombreArchivo);
        }            

        string path = "~/App_Data/" + IdPerAlumno + "/Expediente/" + NombreArchivo + ".pdf";
        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);

        if (File.Exists(root))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(root, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            return result;

        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, root);
        }
    }
```

Y en la url del navegador es: `[object%20HTMLUnknownElement]`
y no se muestra el archivo PDF en el navegador.

Comment: El problema viene de "resultado". Asegúrate que resultado tiene el valor que necesitas. Quizás en vez de crear un blob yo haría un location.href o mostraría el PDF en un inframe (ventana modal). Puedes poner el contenido de "Resultado" en el post?

Comment: si tienes la url del documento y es accesible, solo abre una nueva pestaña (o pon la url en un objecto html `<a/>`) con esa url o bien pon la url en un objeto html de tipo `<object></object>` o `<iframe></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Hola acabo de probar esto:

Este es el metodo  de la WebApi

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {

        var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files/DME1.pdf");
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        return result;
    }
```

En javascript solo utilice este

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:62405/api/metodo';
```

Espero que te funcione hermano.

Comment: Estas url para que sirve? 'http://localhost:62405/api/metodo'

Comment: Seria para abrir o descargar el archivo desde javascript. window.location.href = 'http://localhost:62405/api/metodo'; Esa url es la de la api que tiene el endpoint que muestra el archivo.